# Animation not working when it comes from a notification

Tags: objective-c, animation, segue, nsnotification

Working in an app with `Objective-C` I got the next problem:

I have a code that executes an animation in a `UIViewController` that is called with input from the user and also when a `push notification` comes from other user using this app.

The matter is that the first time i enter this `UIViewController` it works fine, but when `unwind-segue` and `segue` again to this `UIViewController` the animation that is executed with the notification code stops working. The code is being executed but the animation isn't showing. The `segues` are working modally.

If you need to see some code please tell me.

Comment: ofcourse post some cod eplz

Answer (score 0):

Thanks T_77 i found the solution to this problem.

It seems like i have some timers that wasn't being invalidated. Invalidating them at ViewWillDessapear did the fix.